# Swiper carousel not pausing on hover or mouseenter/leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I've got a continuous scrolling Swiper carousel that is using `autoplay`. However the carousel doesn't stop/pause on `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. It's also ignoring the `autoplay` setting `pauseOnMouseEnter: true`.

I then tried to put together a basic script together to see if I could force it myself without using `pauseOnMouseEnter`. But the below also doesn't work.

```
$(".mySwiper").mouseenter(function() {
    scrollc.autoplay.stop();
    console.log('slider stopped');
});

$(".mySwiper").mouseleave(function() {
    scrollc.autoplay.start();
    console.log('slider started again');
});
```

I'm not sure why the pausing is being ignored as it's being logged in the console.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    
    }
    
    .swiper-wrapper {
    transition-timing-function: linear!important;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      max-width: 660px;
      background: red;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    const scrollc = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      spaceBetween: 40,
        effect: 'slide',
        loop: true,
        freeMode: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        speed: 5000,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 1,
            pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
            waitForTransition: true,
            stopOnLastSlide: false,

        }
    });
    
    $(".mySwiper").mouseenter(function() {
        scrollc.autoplay.stop();
        console.log('slider stopped');
    });

    $(".mySwiper").mouseleave(function() {
        scrollc.autoplay.start();
        console.log('slider started again');
    });
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```